# Default values subject to existential constraint in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, existential-type

Consider the following typeclass that defines pairs of types:

```
class Constraint a b where
  g :: a -> b
```

For all instances of constraint we can derive a set of types `a`, essentially an implicit typeclass, let's call it `A`. For each instance of typeclass `A` there is another implicit typeclass `B` which is includes all possible types `b` for `Constraint A b`.

So here is a piece of code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Debug.Trace

-- Contraining class
class (Show a, Show b) => QandA a b where
  g :: a -> b

-- Some data types
data A = A1 | A2 deriving (Show, Eq)
data B = B1 | B2 deriving (Show, Eq)
data C = C1 | C2 deriving (Show, Eq)

instance QandA A B where
  g A1 = B1
  g A2 = B2

instance QandA A C where
  g A1 = C1
  g A2 = C2

-- We want to define a set of types that includes all the types that
-- have Constraint a b given a. This can be done via an intermediate
-- type.
data DefaultAnswer q = forall a . (DefaultingQuestion q, QandA q a) => DefaultAnswer {answer :: a};

-- Polymorphism
class DefaultingQuestion q where
  def :: DefaultAnswer q

instance DefaultingQuestion A where
  def = DefaultAnswer C1
```

Which typechecks but in ghci

```
> (def :: DefaultAnswer A)
(def :: DefaultAnswer A) :: DefaultAnswer A
```

But

```
> answer (def :: DefaultAnswer A)
<interactive>:574:1:
    Cannot use record selector "answer" as a function due to escaped type variables
    Probable fix: use pattern-matching syntax instead
    In the expression: answer (def :: DefaultAnswer A)
    In an equation for "it": it = answer (def :: DefaultAnswer A)
```

Now the way I understand it is that, since I use existential types, GHC does not really look for the type of `answer`, it just makes sure there could be one even if it has no way of figuring out which one it is. So then when I actually want to run `answer` it can't figure out how to deal with it.

So my question is: is there a way to define a default answer for each type that implements `DefaultingQuestion`

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, unless you want to add a `Typeable` constraint or something. Can you give some concrete examples of why you want this?

Comment: The `Typeable` (or `Data`) constraint is an acceptable compromise, but I couldn't figure out how to do it event with those...

Comment: This code is so ... weird ... that I can't give any concrete advice without more background about what, concretely, you're trying to accomplish. Do you have a use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
import Data.Proxy

class DefaultingQuestion q a where
  def :: Proxy q -> a

instance DefaultingQuestion A where
  def _ = C1
```

Comment: Yes proxy was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for